# Implementing Oracle Object Type in C# / Dot net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, plsql, odp.net

we are implementing oracle object type and its method in C#, we followed below link,
http://www.magic-dev.com/map-udt-asp-net-oracle.htm

but ODP.Net is only converting the Attributes to C# Class, we need to know how to implement Oracle Object TYpe methods directly in C# without using wrapped oracle Package. Please share your ideas.

We are using ODP.NET 11.2

Comment: I have no experience with this, but [this section of the Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/featUDTs.htm) claims it's supported. There's a lot of info there but unfortunately no examples. Still, hope it helps :)

Comment: also see [here](http://developergeeks.com/article/48/3-steps-to-implement-oracle-udt-in-odpnet) for an example with code.  To execute a method, 1.Set the CommandType as CommandType.StoredProcedure 2. Set the CommandText as "type_name.procedure_name" 3. Execute the command using any of the Execute methods on the OracleCommand object.

Comment: @ed gibbs: In java it is generating methods directly but in C# it is just generating attributes.

Comment: @tbone: thanks for your reply but this example is same as mine, my problem is that if you create a method inside your type it your type, it would not generate it.